# jquery masonry not working in ie9: beginner

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, responsive-design, jquery-masonry

I am just getting started so I am not sure why this isn't working, but I am trying to use jquery masonry. This seems to work in FF but not IE9?

markup

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <div>Here Goes..</div>
    <div id="list">
        <div class="tile" style="height: 14em;"></div>
        <div class="tile" style="height: 26em;"></div>
        <div class="tile" style="height: 8em;"></div>
        <div class="tile" style="height: 14em;"></div>
        <div class="tile" style="height: 8em;"></div>
        <div class="tile" style="height: 18em;"></div>
        <div class="tile" style="height: 16em;"></div>
        <div class="tile" style="height: 12em;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
body
        {
            background-color: #545e5d;
            padding: 3.75em 1.875em;
        }
        strong
        {
            font-weight: 700;
        }
        h1
        {
            font-size: 1.625em;
            font-style: italic;
            letter-spacing: -0.1em;
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 1.875em; 
        }
            h1,
            h1 a
            {
                color: #fff;
                color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .5 );
            }
                h1 a:hover
                {
                    color: #fff;
                }

        #wrapper
        {
            max-width: 60em;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
            #list
            {
                width: 103.125%; 
                overflow: hidden;
                margin-left: -1.562%;
                margin-bottom: -1.875em; 
            }
                .tile
                {
                    width: 30.303%; 
                    background-color: #fff;
                    background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .5 );
                    float: left;
                    margin: 0 1.515% 1.875em; 
                    background-color:#353535;
                }

        @media only screen and ( max-width: 40em ) 
        {
            .tile
            {
                width: 46.876%; 
                margin-bottom: 0.938em; 
            }
        }

        @media only screen and ( max-width: 20em ) 
        {
            #list
            {
                width: 100%;
                margin-left: 0;
            }
                .tile
                {
                    width: 100%;
                    margin-left: 0;
                    margin-right: 0;
                }
        }
```

js:

```
$( window ).load( function()
    {
    var columns    = 3,
        setColumns = function() { columns = $( window ).width() > 640 ? 3 : $( window ).width() > 320 ? 2 : 1; };

    setColumns();
    $( window ).resize( setColumns );

    $( '#list' ).masonry(
    {
        itemSelector: '.item',
        columnWidth:  function( containerWidth ) { return containerWidth / columns; }
    });
});
```

As I said I am just learning this and wondering what I am missing. I found this concept [here](http://osvaldas.info/responsive-jquery-masonry-or-pinterest-style-layout).

Appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry typo. This doesn't seem to work in IE9 but I have read that it's suppose to, and the demo site provided I can get it to work in IE9. If I view his source there is an additional ie.js going on and I am wondering if there is something additional that I am not aware of to get masonry to work in IE9. I would figure since it's a jquery plug it already should no? Just trying to understand this.

Should have clarified, apologies: By not working I mean the divs are suppose to be centered and even widths on either side, then responsive. When I open in IE, all divs are just horizontal on the left regardless of screen size.

Comment: `$( '#list' ).masonry(` you are selecting an `id` but there is no #list id?

Comment: yep. typo. corrected thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is pretty bad (embarrassing), but I simply typo'd the doctype....wasn't valid. as I said I am a beginner.